# clear method not working with testng but working without it

Tags: java, selenium, testng

.clear() in my test script is not working with testng version 6.14.2 but when i am running the same code without testng the clear method is working as expected.
i am running the code as mentioned below:
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
But this loc is not performing any action.

> Blockquote

Comment: Did you debug to the point where click action is performed when using TestNG?

Comment: yes click action is performed fine but clear is not working

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Please post code snippet of both scenarios.

Comment: element.click(); before element.clear();

Comment: i am not getting any error message its just that loc is not getting executed. I have also tried .click() before clear but still that doesn't work.

Comment: Please post page source code.

Comment: <input type="email" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="jss322 jss292  jss326" id="email" required="" value="">
This is the field for which i am running clear.

Comment: Try with different element locator.

Comment: done that but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

clear() is working for me. refer the following snippet

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testngexample {
    private WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Add chromedriver path chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void GoogleEarch() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("testing");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).clear();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also using the same code but that doesn't work for me. can there be an issue with the testng version ?

Comment: I am using the following environment to execute the mentioned code    1)Chrome version "Version 74.0.3729.169 (64-bit)  " 2) Selenium Language binding is "java-client-7.0.0.jar"  3)Selenium standalone server is "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"  4)TestNg 6.14.2

Comment: when i am running the above code it is working fine, but when i am using .clear() for my site then it is not working. What can be the possible issue ?

Comment: i think the issue is with react input box, if you will try your code on react input box it wont work.